# How to insert create date, modified date and user id by default on insert in yii

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii

I am working on yii and want a functionality to auto insert `created` , `modified` and `user_id`(my column names in db). I am currently doing this with following way . I have to  add this code in every model .

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        ......
        array('created, modified', 'default', 'value'=>new CDbExpression('NOW()'), 'setOnEmpty' => false, 'on' => 'insert'),
        array('modified', 'default', 'value' => new CDbExpression('NOW()'), 'setOnEmpty' => false, 'on' => 'update'),
        array('user_id', 'default', 'value' => Yii::app()->user->id, 'setOnEmpty' => false,'on' => 'insert'),
        array('id, feed_id, user_id, text, created, modified', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
       ..........
    );
}
```

this is working on `insert` and `update`, But I want is

> That if here is a method so that i have to insert it in one file and
>   no need to insert this in every model . If it is possible

Comment: create a function in your model `beforeSave`.

Comment: but in this also i have to create `beforeSave` function in every model. I want to insert this once in one file only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have several models and want to implement common behaviour on them, you can use a custom component and use any of given methods in comments and other answers (behaviors, rules, beforeSave, etc) and extending it for all models.

Create a new file in `protected/components` called for example `MasterModel.php`. In this example I want to inherit `beforeSave` method for all models. Fill `MasterModel.php` with:

```
<?php

abstract class MasterModel extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function beforeSave()
    {
        $current_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        if ( $this->isNewRecord )
        {
           $this->created = $current_time;
           $this->created_by = Yii::app()->user->id;
        }
        if ( ! $this->isNewRecord )
        {
           $this->updated = $current_time;
           $this->updated_by = Yii::app()->user->id;
        }
        return parent::beforeSave();
    }
}
```

Replace on all your existing and future model definitions:

```
<?php

class Client extends ActiveRecord
{
    ....
```

With:

```
<?php

class Client extends MasterModel
{
    ....
```

Make sure to have on your database tables and models:

- created DATETIME
- created_by INT
- updated DATETIME
- updated_by INT

Comment: this is the solution i was looking for . thanks dude.

Comment: Where can I create this MasterModel in Yii2 ?

Comment: @Pravin Step1:Make a folder named "components" in your project root folder. step2: write your custom component inside components folder eg:MyComponent.php. Step3:Add your component inside the config/web.php file. Step4:You are done!. Now you can use your component method  inside any of your app. Taken from http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/747/write-use-a-custom-component-in-yii2-0/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in three ways:

1) Update via model’s rules:

```
public function rules()
{
  return array(
    array('title','length','max'=>255),
    array('title, created_at, updated_at', 'required'),
    array('updated_at','default',
          'value'=>new CDbExpression('NOW()'),
          'setOnEmpty'=>false,'on'=>'update'),
    array('created_at,updated_at','default',
          'value'=>new CDbExpression('NOW()'),
          'setOnEmpty'=>false,'on'=>'insert'),
   array('user_id','default',
          'value'=> Yii::app()->user->id,
          'setOnEmpty'=>false,'on'=>'insert')
  );
}
```

2) Another to use `beforeSave()` as follows:

```
public function beforeSave() {
    if ($this->isNewRecord)
    $this->created_at = new CDbExpression('NOW()');
    $this->user_id = Yii::app()->user->id;
    $this->updated_at = new CDbExpression('NOW()');

    return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

3) Another alternative to use `CTimestampBehavior` in your models:

```
public function behaviors()
{
  return array(
    'CTimestampBehavior'=>array(
        'class'=>'zii.behaviors.CTimestampBehavior',
        'createAttribute'=>'created_at',
        'updateAttribute'=>'updated_at',
        'setUpdateOnCreate'=>true,
        'timestampExpression'=>new CDbExpression('NOW()');
    )
 );
}
```

Make sure your every table has same field name `created_at`, `updated_at` and `user_id`.

Comment: in which file i have to use option 3??  have to create `CTimestampBehavior.php` in the model?

Comment: `behavior()` used in model and `CTimestampBehavior` is in built-in class of `zii.behaviors.CTimestampBehavior`.

Comment: then i have to create `behavior()` in every model . But i want something like cake php . no need to define in model it'll automatically insert the date if field is `created` `modified` `user_id`

Comment: i don't know , it is possible or not in yii.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very usefull article here [how to insert autofill yii model data](http://codingbin.com/yii-model-auto-insert-fields/)

you just need to create a class as @Alejandro Quiroz answered . The issue in that answer was if field is not available it throws an exception so here is the best solution i found. you need to check if attribute available with `if($this->hasAttribute('modified'))`

```
public function beforeSave()
 {
 $current_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 if ( $this->isNewRecord )
 {
 if($this->hasAttribute('created'))
 $this->created = $current_time;

if($this->hasAttribute('modified'))
 $this->modified = $current_time;

if($this->hasAttribute('user_id')) // make sure user field name i user_id
 $this->user_id = Yii::app()->user->id;
 }
 if ( ! $this->isNewRecord )
 {
 if($this->hasAttribute('modified'))
 $this->modified = $current_time;
 /* remove this if want updated by id */
 //$this->updated_by = Yii::app()->user->id;
 }
 return parent::beforeSave();
 }
```